# Find difference between dates in YYYYmmddHHMMSSfraction format

Tags: python, datetime

I have two timestamps like this:
They are in the format: `YYYYmmddHHMMSSfraction`

```
t1=20131229135931664000
t2=20131229140021638000
```

How can find the difference in the timestamps in seconds?

Comment: Or are these meant to be `YYYYmmddHHMMSSfraction` formatted? Or are they microseconds since the epoch? How will we ever guess? You do need to tell us a) what format these are in and b) why other posts here on Stack Overflow didn't work for you.

Comment: Yes thats right..YYYYmmddHHMMSSfraction.  Sorry about that

Comment: So are they strings or integers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parse out the format using `datetime.datetime.strptime()`:

```
import datetime

format = '%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f'
dt1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(t1), format)
dt2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(t2), format)

difference = (dt2 - dt1).total_seconds()
```

Comment: @AlexThornton: nope, I didn't start until the OP confirmed the format.